# Tampermonkey script not auto-updating

Tags: userscripts, tampermonkey

At the top of my script I have the following:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test script
// @description  testing auto-update
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @author       newbie
// @version      1.0.0
// @updateURL    https://github.com/mygithubaccount/test/raw/master/test.user.js
// @downloadURL  https://github.com/mygithubaccount/test/raw/master/test.user.js
// @match        http://awebsite.com/*
// @run-at       document-end
// @grant        GM_getResourceText
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant        GM_getResourceURL
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==
```

Please note that these values are just for example.

When I make changes on the script and increase the version number on github and then push the changes to master it updates the raw script link, however I don't get auto-updates from Tampermonkey as in popups saying the script has an update. It will only update if I manually go to the link and reinstall the script to update it.

How can I make this auto-update with popups?

Comment: Check if the new version is really accessible through the URL. It is best to use the same single URL for: install, update and download. Then do not specify `@updateURL` or `@downloadURL` at all. See [Why is usage of the downloadURL & updateURL keys called unusual and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38025376/320437)

Answer (score 12):

I am not an expert at userscripts, can only tell from my experience making TamperMonkey work:

In order for TamperMonkey  to update, I had to copy&paste the URL into *Update URL:* on the script's *Settings* tab: [image: here is a screenshot]

(Make sure ☒ *Check for updates* is turned on, obviously.)

Then if you manually *Check for userscript updates* on the TamperMonkey icon, you should see a proper popup.

Comment: This hint is gold! I changed `// @updateURL ...` in my script after installing since there was a typo, but _Settings_ → _**Updates**_ → _Update URL:_ [...] wasn't changed accordingly.

Comment: Additional note to that: Once you do any change on the Editor tab and save it, the Checkbox `Check for updates` gets turned off.

Comment: When you install the script from a correct URL (on which the new versions will be released) and new versions update `@version` you do not need to specify `@updateURL`. It is even better to not specify it. See [Why is usage of the downloadURL & updateURL keys called unusual and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38025376/320437)