# How to implement auto-update in a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: greasemonkey-4

I am writing a Greasemonkey script, how to implement auto updating?

Is possible put script into GitHub repository and set `@version` number?

And then... is some automatically way how to do it? Or I must manually check.

Comment: What version of Greasemonkey are you using?

Comment: Greasemonkey version 4.5.

Answer (score 8):

As of some time ago, Greasemonkey supports auto updates (it was not the case at the moment the question was asked):

1. Add `@updateURL` to the script meta config. It *can* (but not necessary) be the same as `@downloadURL`.
2. Add `@version` to meta. Each new script version should increment the value.
3. Optionally, the file name should end with `.user.js` for GM to open the installation dialog.

> Is possible put script into GitHub repository and set @version number?

The script can be hosted in GitHub repo or gist. The download and update URLs should link to the raw file, though. To install the script, user will have to open that `@downloadURL`. Here's [the GM wiki page on the subject](https://wiki.greasespot.net/User_Script_Hosting).

Comment: Thanks. This helped me also with `tampermonkey`.

Comment: [Read what](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38025376/3273963) `@updateURL and `@downloadURL do and why in most cases they should not be used.